# CruiseControl.NET Emails not containing build results or errors

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I have some failing builds and the build data is missing from the emails sent from CCNET?

It contains tests run and modifications but no build or error data?

I don't think I have messed up the xsl's.. any thoughts?

**UPDATE :**

Yes i've looked at 
http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Email+Publisher

and Yes in the publishers section i've called xmllogger before email

**UPDATE :**

I'm not sure if this means anything but.. in the compile.xsl it looks for

/cruisecontrol//buildresults//message

but there is no 'buildresults' node??

It just goes..

cruisecontrol --> build --> msbuild (then warnings, project, messages etc etc)

**UPDATE :**

Have the following in ccservice.exe.config. No mention of msbuild??

xsl\header.xsl
 xsl\compile.xsl
 xsl\unittests.xsl
 xsl\fit.xsl
 xsl\modifications.xsl
 xsl\fxcop-summary.xsl

-- Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem yesterday with a new install of cruisecontrol as a service.

Make sure you have specified the correct xsl files in the `ccnetservice.exe.config` (if you are running the service) and `ccnet.exe.config` if you running the console version.

you need to restart the service/console app once these are updated.

HTH

**Edit:**

Are you using the standard msbuild logger, or Rodemeyer's one? If you are using Rodemeyer's, you need to use diffrent XSL transforms (`msbuild2ccnet.xsl`) to normal (`compile.xsl`, `msbuild.xsl`).  There is a guide for that [here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNETCOMM/Improved+MSBuild+Integration)

Check that your output is making it to the build log, located in `server\<projectName>\artifacts`.

If you have modified the xsl, make sure its in the correct folder (`webdashboard\xsl` and `server\xsl`).  You can test the xsl works fine by copying the build log file (see `server\<projectName>\artifacts` directory). to a file, and adding the relevant XSL includes to the header then opening the XML file in a web browser)

**EDIT:**

in the `<xslFiles>` section of ccservice.exe.config, add another line like this:

```
<file name="xsl\compile-msbuild.xsl" />
```

or

```
<file name="xsl\msbuild.xsl" />
```

as i am not using the standard logger (you are though), i am uncertain as to which of those is needed.  try one, then if that doesnt work, try the other!

Comment: Cheers Andy but all SEEMS to be fine in that area.

-- Lee

Comment: Using C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll

Comment: Yes the second one works. Tried it before I saw your update.
Note to others : I think you may have to restart the service befiore changes to the xsl file takes effect.

Cheers for pointing me in the right direction Andy,

-- Le

Comment: compile-msbuild.xsl seems to be a summary where msbuild is EVERYTHING in the build. I think compile-msbuild.xsl is more appropriate for an email. -- Lee